# How sum two rows in Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

```
name  value
C202  1500
C203  2000
C204  3000
H202  1300
H203  500
H204  150
```

Here is some example of my date. I want to sum value if names are the same (except first letter) i.e. C202 and H202 (1500+1300), C203 and H203. First letter is always C or H.
Any idea how to do that in Access 2010?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Right(name, 3), sum (value)
from Table1
group by Right(name, 3);
```

Results are

```
202 2800
203 2500
204 3150
```